# Why isn't androidx PreferenceDataStore working?

Tags: sharedpreferences, androidx

I tried to use androidx PreferenceDataStore as in [this example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/use-saved-values) but it did not work, no matter what I tried.
It always uses the default shared preferences.
How can I make it to use custom data store?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed my shared preferences, and I don't need PreferenceDataStore anymore.